# In Ruby, I cannot get .titleize to work within the class initialize

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm a beginner ruby programmer who is just trying to learn. I've been playing with this little bit of code that I wrote all by myself.  I'm trying to use the titleize method within the class but I'm getting an error.  When I use the capitalize method I don't get an error. What am I doing wrong? I'm simply trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in the title string.  And I'm looking for the most simple answer, not necessarily the best or shortest code.  Thanks!

```
class Movie
  def initialize(title, rank, year)
    @title = title.titleize
    @rank = rank
    @year = year
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@rank}: #{@title} (#{@year})"
  end
end

movie1 = Movie.new("the godfather", 1, 1972)
movie2 = Movie.new("gladiator", 2, 2000)
movie3 = Movie.new("the godfather part 2", 3, 1974)
movie4 = Movie.new("the dark knight", 4, 2008)
movie5 = Movie.new("return of the jedi", 5, 1983)
movie6 = Movie.new("star wars", 6, 1977)
movie7 = Movie.new("meet joe black", 7, 1998)
movie8 = Movie.new("back to the future", 8, 1985)
movie9 = Movie.new("the bourne identity", 9, 2002)
movie10 = Movie.new("a lot like love", 10, 2005)
movies = [movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4, movie5, movie6, movie7, movie8, movie9, movie10]
puts "Robbie's Top #{movies.size} Movies:"
puts movies
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Is there even a `titleize` method? I don't think there is...

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html

Comment: 4:in `initialize': undefined method `titleize' for "the godfather":String(NoMethodError) from top_ten_movies.rb:14:in `new'  from top_ten_movies.rb:14:in `<main>'

Comment: I've read that it is on several sites.  I've also seen it in a list with several common ones, like capitalize.

Comment: Yeah, "undefined method titleize" means that method is undefined (i.e., it doesn't exist).

Comment: `String#titleize` is an ActiveSupport thing. Are you using Rails or manually requiring the appropriate chunks of ActiveSupport?

Comment: I'm just writing Ruby, not Rails. I'll look into Active Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no titleize method in String class in ruby.

You can extend the String class to have a titleize method or use this function separately.

```
class String
  def titleize
    self.split(" ").map{|word| word.capitalize}.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Comment: So where would I call that method?

Comment: either put the code I gave above the movie class. or put it in a separate ruby file and include it in the movie class(so that it can be reused in other files). This code extends the String class to have the titleize method. So your code in initialize method will work.